# Why do we measure time complexity instead of step complexity?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

When I first took a class on algorithms, I was confused as to what was actually being measured when talking about asymptotic *time* complexity, since it sure wasn't the time the computer took to run a program. Instead, my mental model was that we were measuring the asymptotic *step* complexity, that is the asymptotic number of steps the CPU would take to run the algorithm.

Any reason why we reason about time complexity as opposed to step complexity and talk about how much time an algorithm takes as opposed to how many steps (asymptotically) a CPU takes to execute the algorithm?

Comment: Time complexity doesn't measure time, it measures arbitrary units of operation. For example, when we talk about the time complexity of sorting, or hash tables, we usually count comparisons. The steps performed by a turing machine are usually only theoretically interesting since the calculations are difficult for polynomial-time algorithms and they don't model real-world performance well. "Bit model complexity" is most like "steps on a CPU".

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the number of steps is the determining factor, with the condition that the duration of a *step* is not dependent on the input -- it should never take more time than some chosen constant time.

What exactly that constant time is, will depend on the system you run it on. Some CPUs are just faster than others, and some CPUs are more specialised in one kind of operation, and less in another. Two different steps may therefore represent different times: on one CPU step *A* may execute with a shorter delay than step *B*, while on another it may be the inverse. It might even be, that on the same CPU step *A* sometimes can execute faster than other times (for example, because of some favourable condition in the pipe of that CPU).

All that makes it impossible to say something useful by just measuring the time to run a step. Instead, we consider that there is a *maximum* time (for a given CPU) for all the different kinds of "steps" we have identified in the algorithm, such that the individual execution of one step will *never* exceed that maximum time.

So when we talk about time complexity we *do* say something about the time an algorithm will take. If an algorithm has *O(n²)* time complexity, it means we can find a value *minN* and a constant time *C* (we may freely choose those), such that for every *n >= minN*, the total *time* *T* it takes to run the algorithm is bounded by *T < Cn²*. Note especially that *T* and *C* are *not* a number of steps, but really measures of *time* (e.g. milliseconds). However the choice of *C* will depend on the CPU and the maximum we found for its step execution. So we don't actually know which value *C* will have in general, we just prove that such a *C* exists for every CPU (or whatever executes the algorithm).

In short, we make an equivalence between a step and a unit of time, such that the execution of a step is guaranteed to be bounded by that unit of time.

Comment: Hmm, many common time complexities are not measured in "time". For example we count comparisons for hash table operations and sorting algorithms, but on an actual CPU those comparisons may take arbitrarily long (or in your words, it may "take more time than some chosen constant time").

Comment: @PaulHankin, if a comparison on a CPU is not bound by any constant time, then we cannot know that the algorithm will ever end, and any big O expression for the overall time complexity would violate the definition of big O.

Comment: However long comparisons take, a sorting algorithm is bound to complete, but yes you're right that the (walltime) runtime of sorting is not in any complexity class unless you add additional constraints. Can you estimate how long your computer will take to sort n strings using a fixed implementation of quicksort, as only a function of n? Not accurately without adding additional data about the size of the strings.

Comment: Indeed, I definitely argue for defining the time complexity of such stringsorting algorithm on *two* variables (the number of strings and the maximum length of the strings), and the assumption that the size of the characterset is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, we measure the computational steps that an algorithm uses to run on a Turing machine. However, we do not count every single step. Instead, we are typically interested in the run*time* differences of algorithms ignoring constant factors as we do when using the *O-notation*.

Also, I believe the term is quite intuitive to grasp. Everybody has a basic understanding of what you mean when you talk about how much *time* an algorithm takes (I can even explain that to my mother). However, if you talk about how many *steps* an algorithm needs, you may find yourself in a discussion about the computational model (what kind of CPU).

The term *time complexity* isn't wrong (in fact, I believe it is quite what we are looking for). The term *step complexity* would be misleading.

Comment: We use a turing machine model when we're on the more abstract end of complexity theory -- NP complete and so on, but for practical use we count some abstract units of computation (dependent on the problem). And I think you're right we should be talking about computational models some of the time when we do this, but no-one does.